# XPath Expression for datetime.iso8601 tag

Tags: xml, qt, xpath, qml

I have this sample XML-RPC response:

```
<struct>
    <member><name>post_id</name><value><string>131</string></value></member>
    <member><name>post_title</name><value><string>Test with secret password</string></value></member>
    <member><name>post_date</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>20080404T09:38:05</dateTime.iso8601></value></member>
    <member><name>post_thumbnail</name><value><string>http://localhost/~herop-kde/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/thumbnails/119.jpg</string></value></member>
</struct>
```

I need to query the dateTime using dateTime() function (and other date/time relating functions) in QML. Using this query always returns error:

```
struct/member[name='post_date']/value/dateTime.iso8601/dateTime()
```

The error:

```
Error XPST0017 in [...] at line 2, column 96: fn:dateTime($arg1 as xs:date?, $arg2 as xs:time?) as xs:dateTime? requires at least 2 argument(s). 0 is therefore invalid.
[...]/Main.qml:37:13: QML XmlRole: invalid query: "struct/member[name='post_date']/value/dateTime.iso8601/dateTime()"
```

I still can use that format to query other fields successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If xml contains properly formatted iso8601 date (2008-04-04T09:38:05) you could use `xs:dateTime` function:

```
ListView {
    // ...
    model: XmlListModel {
        // ...
        query: "/struct/member"
        XmlRole {
            name: "dateTime"
            query: "xs:dateTime(value/dateTime.iso8601)"
        }
    }
    delegate: Text {
        text: model.dateTime
    }
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to get it as string and do conversion/formatting in your javascript code.

Comment: Wordpress returns the date as 20080404T09:38:05 without the hyphen between year, month and day. I think that's the reason for the error I'm seeing. My solution is to fetch the timestamp instead of the dateTime from WP and use JS to parse it.